# 'cannot resolved to a variable' error: ImageDisplayView

Tags: java, android

```
public class ImageDisplayView1
  extends View
  implements View.OnTouchListener
{
  public static float MAX_SCALE_RATIO = 5.0F;
  public static float MIN_SCALE_RATIO = 0.1F;
  float bitmapCenterX;
  float bitmapCenterY;
  int displayCenterX = 0;
  int displayCenterY = 0;
  float displayHeight = 0.0F;
  float displayWidth = 0.0F;
  float distanceThreshold = 3.0F;
  boolean isScrolling = false;
  int lastX;
  int lastY;
  Bitmap mBitmap;
  Canvas mCanvas;
  Context mContext;
  Matrix mMatrix;
  Paint mPaint;
  float oldDistance = 0.0F;
  int oldPointerCount = 0;
  float scaleRatio;
  Bitmap sourceBitmap;
  float sourceHeight = 0.0F;
  float sourceWidth = 0.0F;
  public float startX;
  public float startY;
  float totalScaleRatio;

  public ImageDisplayView1(Context paramContext)
  {
    super(paramContext);
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    init();
  }

  public ImageDisplayView1(Context paramContext, AttributeSet paramAttributeSet)
  {
    super(paramContext, paramAttributeSet);
    this.mContext = paramContext;
    init();
  }

  private void init()
  {
    this.mPaint = new Paint();
    this.mMatrix = new Matrix();
    this.lastX = -1;
    this.lastY = -1;
    setOnTouchListener(this);
  }

  private void moveImage(float paramFloat1, float paramFloat2)
  {
    Log.d("test", "moveImage() called : " + paramFloat1 + ", " + paramFloat2);
    this.mMatrix.postTranslate(paramFloat1, paramFloat2);
    redraw();
  }

  private void scaleImage(float paramFloat)
  {
    Log.d("test", "scaleImage() called : " + paramFloat);
    this.mMatrix.postScale(paramFloat, paramFloat, this.bitmapCenterX, this.bitmapCenterY);
    this.mMatrix.postRotate(0.0F);
    this.totalScaleRatio = (paramFloat * this.totalScaleRatio);
    redraw();
  }

  public void drawBackground(Canvas paramCanvas)
  {
    if (paramCanvas != null) {
      paramCanvas.drawColor(-16777216);
    }
  }

  public void newImage(int paramInt1, int paramInt2)
  {
    Bitmap localBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(paramInt1, paramInt2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas localCanvas = new Canvas();
    localCanvas.setBitmap(localBitmap);
    this.mBitmap = localBitmap;
    this.mCanvas = localCanvas;
    this.displayWidth = paramInt1;
    this.displayHeight = paramInt2;
    this.displayCenterX = (paramInt1 / 2);
    this.displayCenterY = (paramInt2 / 2);
  }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas paramCanvas)
  {
    if (this.mBitmap != null) {
      paramCanvas.drawBitmap(this.mBitmap, 0.0F, 0.0F, null);
    }
  }

  protected void onSizeChanged(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, int paramInt3, int paramInt4)
  {
    if ((paramInt1 > 0) && (paramInt2 > 0))
    {
      newImage(paramInt1, paramInt2);
      redraw();
    }
  }

  public boolean onTouch(View paramView, MotionEvent paramMotionEvent)
  {
    int i = paramMotionEvent.getAction();
    int j = paramMotionEvent.getPointerCount();
    switch (i)
    {
    default: 
    case 0: 
    case 2: 
      float f9;
      for (;;)
      {
        return true;
        if (j == 1)
        {
          float f15 = paramMotionEvent.getX();
          float f16 = paramMotionEvent.getY();
          this.startX = f15;
          this.startY = f16;
        }
        for (;;)
        {
          return true;
          if (j == 2)
          {
            this.oldDistance = 0.0F;
            this.isScrolling = true;
          }
        }
        if (j == 1)
        {
          if (this.isScrolling) {
            return true;
          }
          f11 = paramMotionEvent.getX();
          f12 = paramMotionEvent.getY();
          if (this.startX == 0.0F)
          {
            this.startX = f11;
            this.startY = f12;
            return true;
          }
          f13 = this.startX - f11;
          f14 = this.startY - f12;
          if (this.oldPointerCount != 2)
          {
            if (this.totalScaleRatio > 1.0F) {
              moveImage(-f13, -f14);
            }
            this.startX = f11;
            this.startY = f12;
          }
        }
        while (j != 2)
        {
          float f11;
          float f12;
          float f13;
          float f14;
          this.oldPointerCount = j;
          break;
        }
        float f3 = paramMotionEvent.getX(0);
        float f4 = paramMotionEvent.getY(0);
        float f5 = paramMotionEvent.getX(1);
        float f6 = paramMotionEvent.getY(1);
        float f7 = f3 - f5;
        float f8 = f4 - f6;
        f9 = FloatMath.sqrt(f7 * f7 + f8 * f8);
        if (this.oldDistance != 0.0F) {
          break;
        }
        this.oldDistance = f9;
      }
      float f10;
      if (f9 > this.oldDistance)
      {
        if (f9 - this.oldDistance < this.distanceThreshold) {
          return true;
        }
        f10 = this.scaleRatio + 0.05F * (this.oldDistance / f9);
        label335:
        if ((f10 >= MIN_SCALE_RATIO) && (f10 <= MAX_SCALE_RATIO)) {
          break label439;
        }
        Log.d("test", "Invalid scaleRatio : " + f10);
      }
      for (;;)
      {
        this.oldDistance = f9;
        break;
        boolean bool = f9 < this.oldDistance;
        f10 = 0.0F;
        if (!bool) {
          break label335;
        }
        if (this.oldDistance - f9 < this.distanceThreshold) {
          return true;
        }
        f10 = this.scaleRatio - 0.05F * (f9 / this.oldDistance);
        break label335;
        label439:
        Log.d("test", "Distance : " + f9 + ", ScaleRatio : " + f10);
        scaleImage(f10);
      }
    }
    if (j == 1)
    {
      float f1 = paramMotionEvent.getX();
      float f2 = paramMotionEvent.getY();
      (this.startX - f1);
      (this.startY - f2);
    }
    for (;;)
    {
      return true;
      this.isScrolling = false;
    }
  }

  public void recycle()
  {
    if (this.sourceBitmap != null) {
      this.sourceBitmap.recycle();
    }
  }

  public void redraw()
  {
    if (this.sourceBitmap == null) {
      return;
    }
    drawBackground(this.mCanvas);
    float f1 = (this.displayWidth - this.sourceBitmap.getWidth()) / 2.0F;
    float f2 = (this.displayHeight - this.sourceBitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0F;
    this.mCanvas.translate(f1, f2);
    this.mCanvas.drawBitmap(this.sourceBitmap, this.mMatrix, this.mPaint);
    this.mCanvas.translate(-f1, -f2);
    invalidate();
  }

  public void setImageData(Bitmap paramBitmap)
  {
    recycle();
    this.sourceBitmap = paramBitmap;
    this.sourceWidth = this.sourceBitmap.getWidth();
    this.sourceHeight = this.sourceBitmap.getHeight();
    this.bitmapCenterX = (this.sourceBitmap.getWidth() / 2);
    this.bitmapCenterY = (this.sourceBitmap.getHeight() / 2);
    this.scaleRatio = 1.0F;
    this.totalScaleRatio = 1.0F;
  }
}
```

I'm getting errors with `f11`, `f12`, `f13` and `f14`, where they can't be resolved to a variable. Can anybody help? Also, are there any syntax errors?

Comment: Your errors are not eclipse's fault

Comment: They might be, because it's an import of a code I directly imported from a working application.

Comment: You are using `f11` and `f12` before you have declared them.

Comment: f11 = paramMotionEvent.getX();
f12 = paramMotionEvent.getY();

Comment: Isn't that a declaration? same for f13 and f14

Comment: No. You must do something like `float f11 = paramMotionEvent.getX();` Notice the type declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet from your question

```
        this.startX = f11;
        this.startY = f12;
      }
    }
    while (j != 2)
    {
      float f11;
      float f12;
```

As you can see, you are using them before declaring them. Also, you are declaring them inside of a while loop which will make them unusable elsewhere. In fact, the way they are declared makes them completely unusable in your entire program and are doing exactly *nothing*.

At the very beginning of your program where you have

```
float bitmapCenterX;
float bitmapCenterY;
```

and other declarations, add the lines

```
float f11;
float f12;
float f13;
float f14;
```

Comment: Also, by looking at your other questions I see you have lots of errors stemming from taking an apk and turning it back into java source. When source is turned into an apk, lots of changes are made and when you reverse them, things don't go back exactly the way they were. Hope that helps you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

```
  f11 = paramMotionEvent.getX();
  f12 = paramMotionEvent.getY();
```

Where have you declared these f11 and f12..

Remember declaring

```
while (j != 2)
        {
          float f11;
          float f12;
          float f13;
          float f14;
          this.oldPointerCount = j;
          break;
        }
```

will make f11 and f12 available "only inside the loop".. also, you are using your variables before declaring them..

Comment: does this mean if i add float to the start of each of my declaration, it works?

Comment: yes.. declare your variables at the beginning (before using them) of your function, it will work...you can declare them anywhere in your function, outside any inner { } block... They can be accessed in other parts of the function.. but its a good programming practice to declare them at the beginning..